# How to Volume control PAM8610 from RPI

Tags: pi-3, audio, python-3

Does anyone know how can I control PAM8610 module volume through code from RPI?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "control"? AFAIK the only digital input on PAM8610 is "Mute". You can control that one with a GPIO.

Comment: I was saying about volume increasing decreasing (Fading) etc. Only mute? :O

Comment: @El_Dorado, You can tap the PAM8610's digital volume pin out and use Rpi python to control volume using a DAC or digital pot.  You might like to read my answer to the question of using the digital pot MCP4725, with demo code. ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83405/dac-mcp4725-not-working-with-raspberry )

Comment: wohh...that is some deep ***. I first have to learn about that code and then try to replicate for PAM8610. Thanks, man.

Comment: @El_Dorado, I agree it is "deep".  But you can go slowly step by step, from the "shallow" end: (1) Rpi python GPIO to blink a led, (2) Rpi python GPIO to read a button, (3) ADC, (4) DAC, (5) Well, you are almost there.  I actually went through the above steps, from the shallow end, and now I am swimming happily at the "deep" end.  It took me, with an IQ of 93, 500+ hobbyist hours. Of course you might not need that long.  But no pain no gain! :)

Comment: Yeah, I will work hard on this.